# Using Lift with other front end web frameworks?

Tags: scala, lift

Can anyone comment on experience using Lift with other front end web frameworks (e.g. Rails, PHP, etc) to generate snippets/partial pages? If so, what were the pain points (if any)? Even if you haven't tried it: potentially useful concept or would this be a mistake?

Comment: From what I've seen of Lift, it likes to be a front to back end platform. If you're looking for a back end without the Lift trappings and you like Scala, check out Akka - you can do almost anything you need with it. Good luck!

Comment: Rails and PHP are not front-end frameworks, they're backend frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Lift is actually doing a Ruby-variant now, check the google Groups.

Also PHP and Rails are both not backend frameworks. PHP is a language for one, but both of them are not usable for backends. They all are more or less request-cycle-based, that makes them both not usable for backend systems.

lift/scala is the way to go for everything from frontend to backend (actors, akka, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use lift for back end as well as front end, but you could use lift as a rest service and use any front end like GWT, plain jQuery, etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Lift as a portal framework, with various GWT applications inside the same tomcat container.

Authentication happens via lift, and calls a hidden GWT app form to set a session id (the user data is in the same Postgres db).

It's the best of both worlds - Lift lets me create a stable, ORM enabled website with lots of piping already done, and for all in depth data analysis (it's a finance related app), I link to the GWT app - mostly for cell widgets / charts.